# Start a program or filepath remotely

Tags: powershell, command, prompt

With XP machines and eventually win7 machines. I am trying to find a way to start a program remotely from the commandline or even powershell if possible. Right now we can kill tasks using the "taskkill" command, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to start them without extra programs. I want to be able to do it without deploying anything. I tried that Psexec but that didnt work.

Comment: Since XP doesn't ship with PowerShell I don't see how PowerShell can help you.  It would help if you can state what OS's will be running on the Remote machines and if you need the program to be visible on the logged in user's desktop.

Comment: Well if it's not possible with commandline, powershell will have to do. All the machines will be win7 eventually, but how would I go about doing this? OR could I do schedule tasks from commandline? Since we do IT work I wanted to "taskkill" the process and start it again with a command.

Comment: Do you need the logged on user to be able to see any UI the process wants to display?  Also, *why* didn't psexec work for you?

Comment: Uh not sure about if seeing the UI matters. And with psexec you  need to have that on every system to use it. That is not currently possible.

Comment: You do realize that PowerShell is not installed by default on XP and you say you can't use something that requires installation.  Are you OK with requiring PowerShell to be installed on XP?

Comment: Well I'm thinking more of the future so that would be okay for windows 7.

Comment: You do NOT have to have PsExec on every computer, just on the computer where you are running it from. As long as you have the admin rights on remote computers, it will create a temporary PsExecSvc and process your command.

Comment: But it didnt work when I tried it and I do have admin access to kill programs and remote connect and lock accounts etc.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01  -ScriptBlock { yourprogram.exe }

Check out technet:

The Invoke-Command cmdlet runs commands on a local or remote computer and returns all output from the commands, including errors. With a single Invoke-Command command, you can run commands on multiple computers.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

Comment: [c78572] Connecting to remote server c78572 failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the
destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests.
Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or
WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure
the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: Have you run the PowerShell command `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned; Enable-PSRemoting -force` from an elevated (admin) PowerShell prompt on the remote computer?  If not, do that then try the Invoke-Command again on the local computer but make sure you're running from an elevated PowerShell prompt.  Also, do your credentials have admin privileges on the remote computer? If not, then you'll need to supply credentials that do have admin privs.

Comment: Does that set the Execution Policy to Unrestricted forever or just for that one time?

Comment: This will execute something on a remote machine, but don't expect any user on the remote machine to ever see any UI from it.

Comment: But it doesn't change their execution policy to unrestricted ? I dont want to open any security holes.